# onChange for imported class property in Ionic/Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to monitor the change of a property that is imported from a plugin I'm using.

`this._audioProvider.tracks[0].progress` will update while an audio track is playing and is of the `number` type.

There is no way for me to currently use `.subscribe()` on it and I don't know how I would be able to watch it for changes. Currently I'm attempting the `ngOnChanges()` function but don't seem to be getting what I want.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  console.log(this._audioProvider.tracks[0].progress);
}
```

How would I simply subscribe to this property and get it's value as it's updated?

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: What plugin are you using?

Comment: @AndrewLively Ionic-Audio

Comment: how about a getter on a property that will return this._audioProvider.tracks[0].progress?

Comment: I think you should create an interval to check the value each amount of time